# Excel range subtraction, overlooking errors in some cells possible?

Tags: vba, excel, range, subtraction

I am having trouble figuring out how to subtract two ranges from each other, some cells in range H:H have "#N/A" while in range D:D there are no errors. I know in Excel it's a simple "=H2-D2" and drag that down but I'm in the process of recording a Macro and wanted to automate the subtraction as well. So far this is what I have:

```
Dim quantity1, quantity2, rIntersect, Qdiff, x  As Range

Set quantity1 = Range("D:D")
Set quantity2 = Range("H:H")

Set rIntersect = Intersect(quantity1, quantity2)

For Each x In quantity1
If Intersect(rIntersect, x) Is Nothing Then
    If Qdiff Is Nothing Then
        Set Qdiff = x
    Else
        Set Qdiff = Application.Union(Qdiff, x)
    End If
End If
Next x

Range("J2").Select
Dim lastRowJ As Long
lastRowJ = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & lastRowJ)
```

Comment: Hi. What are you trying to do in addition to the subtraction? Actually, I don't see the subtraction being done here. Since quantity1 and quantity2 are parallel to each other, rIntersect will always be Nothing.

Comment: I just want to have column J = D - H, I've been trying a couple of things even `Qdiff.Value = quantity1.Value  - quantity2.Value` and then doing the autofill yet that gives me errors since some values in quantity2 are `#N/A`

Comment: Can I help you further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this procedure in a standard code module:

```
Public Sub Subtract()
    [j2:j99] = [h2:h99-d2:d99]
End Sub
```

If you like how that works, I'm happy to embellish it so that it is not hard-coded for 98 rows only. Let me know.

**UPDATE**

Here is a version that will deal with any number of rows. It keys off of column D. So if there are 567 numbers in column D, then you will get 567 corresponding (subtracted) results in column J.

This assumes that the data start in row 2, and that there are no blank cells until the numbers in column D end.

If you are going to call this from the Macro Dialog then you should keep it Public. If on the other hand you are going to call it from another procedure in the same module, then you can make it Private.

Here is the enhanced solution:

```
Public Sub Subtract()
    Dim k&
    Const F = "iferror(h2:h[]-d2:d[],0)"
    k = [count(d:d)]
    [j2].Resize(k) = Evaluate(Replace(F, "[]", k + 1))
End Sub
```

Note that the routine now handles the errors and places a ZERO value in column J when the corresponding value in column H is an error. If you would prefer to have something other than a ZERO (like a blank for instance) when there are errors in column H, just let me know and I'll update to whatever you want.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is how to handle displaying blanks instead of zeroes:

```
Public Sub Subtract()
    Dim k&
    Const F = "iferror(if(h2:h[]-d2:d[]=0,"""",h2:h[]-d2:d[]),0)"
    k = [count(d:d)]
    [k2].Resize(k) = Evaluate(Replace(F, "[]", k + 1))
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! Yes please, the spreadsheet I am using will have different number of rows at any given time (data gets updated daily) and at times cells might have an error value in them, which is expected in some. Is it better to have this as a private sub? I had everything in one sub. I'm self teaching and I don't want to pick up any bad habits.

Comment: How would I be able to change it to display a blank space? In the macro a zero is an indication that there is no difference between my data, changing that to a blank or a "check" would be better for me.

Comment: @Karla I updated the answer again to meet your need.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the `Dim k& ` works? I haven't seen that type of format.

Comment: @Karla It is just another way of declaring the 'k' variable as a Long type. Not only is it shorter than 'As Long' it is actually much, much older. It has been around since the beginning of the BASIC family of languages.